# Recover sql server table defiinitions only with .ldf file

Tags: sql-server

I deleted a sql server 2008 database by accident, i found an older .ldf file of this database(full recover model), but i dont have the .mdf file.
Tools like SQL log analyser and Apex log require both files .mdf and .ldf files.
Is it possible to recover table and columns names from a .ldf without the .mdf file?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it is not. All actions in the .ldf file use the table definitions contained in the .mdf file to identify any information related to the structure that is needed. Also, tables that are only read (static information) won't have any significant information in the .ldf file.

Comment: Also - just checking - but did you look in the recycle bin for the .mdf file?

Comment: Do you have any backups? That would be a lot easier to recover with...

Comment: The database was showing as suspect in management studio, i just wanted to reattach it, but only option was delete database, i didnt think files would be deleted, if i had renamed or moved the directory...
So because i deleted i n management studio, there is nothing in recycle bin.

Comment: I dont have backups, the only file i have is the log(.ldf) from the day i changed from full recovery model to simple, because the data inside was not important.
But i have a whole application in visual studio that use this database, yesterday i spent 3 hours recreating the database seeking in code table names and columns, but relationships, indexes and columns that are not in the code will be lost..
Thanks for answers